# Can a Terraform GCP Compute Engine template be created that loads a startup_script from a URL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

When building a Compute Engine template I can specify custom metadata key startup-script-url    to load a script from a storage bucket. Can this been done in Terraform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the `metadata` block for the `google_compute_instance_template` resource. Below an example:

```
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "demo" {
  name                    = "demo"
  description             = "Demo instance template for Stack Overflow"
  machine_type            = "n1-standard-2"

  metadata = {
    startup-script-url = "gs://mybucket/myscript.sh"
  }

  disk {
    source_image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    auto_delete  = true
    boot         = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had meta{ startup-script-url = "gs://mybucket/myscript.sh"}, no equals sign. It through an error. It is working as expected now.